# Bash - Combine files in separated sub folders

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

So I'm looking for a way to cat .html files in multiple subfolders, but by keeping them in their place.

Actual situation:

```
$ Folder1
.
├── Subfolder1
│   └── File1.html
    └── File2.html
├── Subfolder2
│   └── File1.html
    └── File2.html
```

Desired outcome:

```
$ Folder1
.
├── Subfolder1
│   └── Mergedfile1.html
    └── File1.html
    └── File2.html
├── Subfolder2
│   └── Mergedfile2.html
    └── File1.html
    └── File2.html
```

So far I've came up with this:

```
find . -type f -name *.html -exec cat {} + > Mergedfile.html
```

But this combines all the files of all the subfolders of Folder1, while I want to keep them separated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think what you want is `-maxdepth 1 -type d` into your `find` command :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like told by AK_ , you can use find with exec.

```
find Folder1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c "rep='{}';cat "'"$rep"'"/*.html > "'"$rep"'"/Mergedfile.html" \;
```

Comment: You can't use `{}` like so! it's dangerous and will not work with all versions of `find`. Dangerous: what happens if there's a file named `'; rm -rf / #`? POSIX clearly states that [If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). So you're usage of `{}` is dangerous and not correct.

Comment: This worked perfectly ! Justed run another command to add the subfolder name afterwars. Thanks a lot @ctac_ !

Answer (score 1):

You can loop on all subfolders with a `for` statement:

```
for i in Folder1/SubFolder*; do
   cat "$i"/File*.html > MergeFile$(echo "$i" | sed 's,.*\([0-9]\+\)$,\1,').html
done
```

Comment: Unquoted variables will work in this limited case, but in order for your code to work in common corner cases, you should *always* quote variables which contain file names with double quotes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable